# Update JSON Array in Postgres with specific key

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a complex array which look like following in a table column:

```
{
"sometag": {},
"where": [
    {
        "id": "Krishna",
        "nick": "KK",
        "values": [
            "0"
        ],
        "function": "ADD",
        "numValue": [
            "0"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "Krishna1",
        "nick": "KK1",
        "values": [
            "0"
        ],
        "function": "SUB",
        "numValue": [
            "0"
        ]
    }
],
"anotherTag": [],
"TagTag": {
    "tt": "tttttt",
    "tt1": "tttttt"
}
```

In this array, I want to update the function and numValue of id: "Krishna".

Kindly help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your expected output? Why is numValue an array?

Comment: numValue can have multiple values.

Expect output:   {
 "sometag": {},
 "where": [
  {
   "id": "Krishna",
   "nick": "KK",
   "values": [
    "0"
   ],
   "function": "ADDITION",
   "numValue": [
    "0","1"
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": "Krishna1",
   "nick": "KK1",
   "values": [
    "0"
   ],
   "function": "SUB",
   "numValue": [
    "0"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "anotherTag": [],
 "TagTag": {
  "tt": "tttttt",
  "tt1": "tttttt"
 }
}

Comment: This would be so much easier with a properly normalized data model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really nasty because

1. Updating an element inside a JSON array always requires to expand the array
2. On-top: The array is nested
3. The identfier for the elements to update is a sibling not a parent, which means, you have to filter by a sibling

So I came up with a solution, but I want to disclaim: You should avoid doing this as regular database action! Better would be:

1. Parsing your JSON in the backend and do the operations in your backend code
2. Normalize the JSON in your database if that would be a common task, meaning: Create tables with appropriate columns and extract your JSON into the table structure. Do not store entire JSON objects in the database! That would make every single task much more easier and incredible more performant!

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1914476598a49a0eaefa522f7394fc24)

```
SELECT
    jsonb_set(                                                                                -- 5
        (SELECT mydata::jsonb FROM mytable), 
        '{where}', 
        updated_array
    )::json
FROM (
    SELECT
        jsonb_agg(                                                                            -- 4
            CASE WHEN array_elem ->> 'id' = 'Krishna' THEN
                jsonb_set(                                                                    -- 3
                    jsonb_set(array_elem.value::jsonb, '{function}', '"ADDITION"'::jsonb),    -- 2
                    '{numValue}', 
                    '["0","1"]'::jsonb
                )
            ELSE array_elem::jsonb END
        ) as updated_array
    FROM mytable,
        json_array_elements(mydata -> 'where') array_elem                                     -- 1
) s
```

1. Extract the nested array elements into one element per row
2. Replace `function` value. Note the casts from type `json` to type `jsonb`. That is necessary because there's no `json_set()` function but only `jsonb_set()`. Naturally, if you just have type `jsonb`, the casts are not necessary.
3. Replace `numValue` value
4. Reaggregate the array
5. Replace the `where` value of the original JSON object with the newly created array object.